# AngularJS Tooltip tooltip-is-open not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, tooltip

I have a modal window which requires a password. If the input was empty then there would be an error, I want to display the tooltip when there's an error

```
<input type='password' class='form-control' id='password' ng-model='user.password' uib-tooltip='{{error_msg}}' tooltip-placement='right' tooltip-trigger='none' tooltip-is-open='true' tooltip-class='tooltip_error' tooltip-enable='{{error}}' autofocus>
```

As it stands, if there are no errors then the tooltip isn't displayed at all. Once there is an error, it displays the error message but I have to hover over the text box to show the tooltip. In the mean time I have set `tooltip-is-open` to `true` to test it out but it is currently not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `interpolation operators({{}})` from your `tooltip-enable` directive to make it work, since it points to `scope` property.

change your code like:

```
<input type='password' class='form-control' id='password' ng-model='user.password' uib-tooltip='tootltip text : {{error_msg}}' tooltip-placement='right' tooltip-trigger='none' tooltip-is-open='true' tooltip-class='tooltip_error' tooltip-enable='error' autofocus>
```

**Update** : `uib-tooltip` directive takes the text as input so we need to put interpolation operator into it. [Read more](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip)

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SIAcpI7posUh130ipGw?p=preview)

Comment: When I remove the `{}` it just prints out 'error_msg' but the bool result for `tooltip-enable` does work as it should.

Comment: @J.Do: you must `error_msg` as $scope  property,example like `$scope.error_msg="error in password"`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had before but it only worked when it was wrapped in `{}`. I also still need to hover over the text box for the tooltip to appear.

Comment: @J.Do: just realised, that `uib-tooltip` directive takes text only, [read here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) , So to utilise it we should include interpolation only in tooltip. [Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JIpK5LI7xKeyeRPNTVcV?p=preview), updating answer too.

Comment: Thanks but I am still having the same issue where I have to hover over the text box to show the tooltip instead of it being active without being hovered when error set to true.

Comment: @J.Do : that's seems really unusual, could you please create or update plunker to reproduce your issue. ?, can't guess without looking into more code.

Answer (score 0):

My project is still running AngularJS.

We did a major update to all dependencies and noticed this was an issue.

```
"angular": "1.7.8",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "2.5.6",
```

Since the upgrade we've just recently noticed that uib-tooltips were not showing on mouse over or when tooltip-enable was set to true.  No matter what instructions I found from their website or other stackoverflow answers, I could not get them to display.  Debugging, I could pause the script and see the uib-tooltip-popup was being added to DOM but its opacity by default is 0.  The element appeared to be missing an '.active' class which I believe changes the opacity to .9 or 1.

To solve quickly, I simply added a .less rule.

```
div[uib-tooltip] {
 &:hover + div[uib-tooltip-popup]{
 opacity: 0.9 !important;
 }
}

div[uib-tooltip-html] {
 &:hover + div[uib-tooltip-html-popup]{
 opacity: 0.9 !important;
 }
}
```

These work for both tooltip and tooltip-html.  HOWEVER, they only work if you are NOT adding it to the body (tooltip-append-to-body).  By default, the tooltip popup element is added as a sibling to the uib-tooltip (at least in angularjs), thus the sibling rule.